# Pass a new activity as main activity to render first

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, tensorflow

This is **ClassifierActivity.java** file which is rendering by default:

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.env.BorderedText;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.env.Logger;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Device;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Model;

public class ClassifierActivity extends CameraActivity implements OnImageAvailableListener {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();
  private static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);
  private static final float TEXT_SIZE_DIP = 10;
  private Bitmap rgbFrameBitmap = null;
  private long lastProcessingTimeMs;
  private Integer sensorOrientation;
  public Classifier classifier;
  private BorderedText borderedText;
  /** Input image size of the model along x axis. */
  private int imageSizeX;
  /** Input image size of the model along y axis. */
  private int imageSizeY;

  @Override
  protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.camera_connection_fragment;
  }

  @Override
  protected Size getDesiredPreviewFrameSize() {
    return DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {
    final float textSizePx =
        TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TEXT_SIZE_DIP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    borderedText = new BorderedText(textSizePx);
    borderedText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    recreateClassifier(getModel(), getDevice(), getNumThreads());
    if (classifier == null) {
      LOGGER.e("No classifier on preview!");
      return;
    }

    previewWidth = size.getWidth();
    previewHeight = size.getHeight();

    sensorOrientation = rotation - getScreenOrientation();
    LOGGER.i("Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: %d", sensorOrientation);

    LOGGER.i("Initializing at size %dx%d", previewWidth, previewHeight);
    rgbFrameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
  }

  @Override
  protected void processImage() {
    rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
    final int cropSize = Math.min(previewWidth, previewHeight);

    runInBackground(
        new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            if (classifier != null) {
              final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
              final List<Classifier.Recognition> results =
                  classifier.recognizeImage(rgbFrameBitmap, sensorOrientation);
              lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
              LOGGER.v("Detect: %s", results);

              runOnUiThread(
                  new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      showResultsInBottomSheet(results);
                      showFrameInfo(previewWidth + "x" + previewHeight);
                      showCropInfo(imageSizeX + "x" + imageSizeY);
                      showCameraResolution(cropSize + "x" + cropSize);
                      showRotationInfo(String.valueOf(sensorOrientation));
                      showInference(lastProcessingTimeMs + "ms");
                    }
                  });
            }
            readyForNextImage();
          }
        });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onInferenceConfigurationChanged() {
    if (rgbFrameBitmap == null) {
      // Defer creation until we're getting camera frames.
      return;
    }
    final Device device = getDevice();
    final Model model = getModel();
    final int numThreads = getNumThreads();
    runInBackground(() -> recreateClassifier(model, device, numThreads));
  }

  private void recreateClassifier(Model model, Device device, int numThreads) {
    if (classifier != null) {
      LOGGER.d("Closing classifier.");
      classifier.close();
      classifier = null;
    }
    if (device == Device.GPU && model == Model.QUANTIZED) {
      LOGGER.d("Not creating classifier: GPU doesn't support quantized models.");
      runOnUiThread(
          () -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPU does not yet supported quantized models.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
          });
      return;
    }
    try {
      LOGGER.d(
          "Creating classifier (model=%s, device=%s, numThreads=%d)", model, device, numThreads);
      classifier = Classifier.create(this, model, device, numThreads);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Failed to create classifier.");
    }

    // Updates the input image size.
    imageSizeX = classifier.getImageSizeX();
    imageSizeY = classifier.getImageSizeY();
  }
}
```

I created a new activity named **Main.java** and I want this activity to render first and pass it **ClassifierActivity.java** as intent by click on button:

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // hide title bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // set button on click to scan where open the camera
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  openActivity();
            }
        });

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.turkey);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void openActivity(){
          Intent i = new Intent(this, ClassifierActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        videoView.resume();
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        videoView.start();
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        videoView.suspend();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

This is old **AndroidManifest.xml** (app running successfully)

```
         <activity
                android:name=".ClassifierActivity"
                android:label="@string/activity_name_classification"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:exported="true" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And I want to run **Main** first. So, I changed ***android:name=".ClassifierActivity"*** from old **AndroidManifest.xml** to ***android:name=".Main"*** (app is stop running):

```
         <activity
                android:name=".Main"
                android:label="@string/activity_name_classification"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:exported="true" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; please write the stack trace in your question to clarify what causes that error to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All activities need to be defined in the `manifest`.

You are replacing the original `Activity` with the new one and now the old one is not defined. So you just need to add it back.

```
   <application
      ...
      />
        <activity
                android:name=".ClassifierActivity"
                android:label="@string/activity_name_classification"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:exported="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".Main"
                android:label="@string/activity_name_classification"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
   </application>
```